# Extracting 3D coordinates from STL files (best case) or DICOM files (worst case) in R

Tags: 3d, imaging, geography, medical

I have found packages to import STL (readSTL function, rgl package) and DICOM files (readDICOMFile function, oro.dicom package) in R.

One of the reasons, I am importing medical images into R is that I want to extract several features from the images:

- surface area of an anatomical site
- x,y,z coordinates for each of ~200 anatomic sites per image

When working with a 2D image, I was able to pick x,y coordinates using WebPlotDigitizer.

I know how to visually map my sites to regions of the medical image, originally a CT scan. **Once it's in R, how can I go about extracting the geographic coordinates and surface area information from the 3D image?**

I would like to later project various features of my analysis onto the coordinates, so this is a necessary step in the data workflow.

Would you happen to be able to point me to R tutorials, vignettes, textbooks or other sources of information that may help me along my way?

Comment: It is interesting for me too. I follow the thread.

Comment: Has anyone solved this yet? I have the same query